# Why can't I pass this LeetCode.290？

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap

question：

**Given a pattern and a string s, find if s follows the same pattern.

Here follow means a full match, such that there is a bijection between a letter in pattern and a non-empty word in s.**

Example :

Input: pattern = "abba", s = "dog cat cat dog"
Output: true

my Code:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean wordPattern(String pattern, String str) {
        String[] words=str.split(" ");

        if (words.length != pattern.length()) {
            return false;

        }
        HashMap<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i= 0;i<pattern.length();++i){// Integer i =0 is Ok, but int i =0 is wrong.
            if (map.put(words[i],i) != map.put(pattern.charAt(i),i) ){
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pattern = "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccdd";
               String s ="s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s s t t";
        Solution s1 = new Solution();
        boolean res = s1.wordPattern(pattern,s);
        System.out.println(res);
     }
}
```

my question is:(There are comments in the code)
I except the result is `true`,but the result is `false`

the `for (Integer i= 0;i<pattern.length();++i)` is ok,for the case
but  `for (int i= 0;i<pattern.length();++i)`is wrong.

[image]

I want to know why it has the difference?

Comment: If you give it an input that should evaluate to false, what happens? are either of these correct?

Comment: I don't understand your  words, I want to know why the 
`for (Integer i= 0;i<pattern.length();++i)` is ok for the case 
but `for (int i= 0;i<pattern.length();++i)`is wrong.

Comment: *maybe* because autoboxing of `int` > 127 is not using the Integer pool? Simple test: `int i = 128; Integer j = i; Integer k = i;` now `j == k` will return `false` (but not if `i = 127` or less) - the Map is storing `Integer` , better use `equals` to compare... as with almost all reference types

Comment: Could you add some debugging to your code?  At what offset, for example does the "wrong" version fail?

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented, comparing `Integer` instances should happen with `equals`, not with `==`. It is possible that two distinct instances of `Integer` represent the same `int` value. Here is how you could make a correct comparison:

```
if (!Objects.equals(map.put(words[i],i), map.put(pattern.charAt(i),i))) {
```